# In how many different ways $2$ girls and $5$ boys can be seated in a row containing $7$ seats so that the two girls sit side by side?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many different ways $2$ girls and $5$ boys can be seated in a
>   row containing $7$ seats so that the two girls sit side by side?

I must find the probability for the girls sitting side by side. We can seat $7$ people in a row containing $7$ seats in $P_7=7!=5040$ ways. What about the favorable outcomes? I remember that we can look at the two girls as one element and think about the possibilities in this way. How to calculate the favorable outcomes?

Comment: Well, treat the girls as a block of length 2, place the block down, then choose who will be first in the block. Then, in the remaining 5 spots, put boys

Comment: First we seat both girls next to each other. For this we have $6\cdot2=12$ possibilities. Afterwards there are $5!$ possibilities. So your probability is $\frac27$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the two girls as a single unit; then the no. of ways to arrange the "unit" and the $5$ boys would be $6!$. But we also have to consider the no. of ways of forming that "unit" - i.e. in how many ways the two girls can be arranged within that unit, which is $2!$. So the total no. of favorable outcomes would be $2!6!$.

Comment: I think I got it. Now I am trying to solve the same problem when we have $8$ people: $5$ boys and $3$ girls; and $8$ seats. If we consider the three girls as a single unit; the number of ways to arrange the "unit" and the $5$ boys would be $6!$. As you said, we have to consider the number of ways of forming that "unit", which is $3!=6$ in this case. So the total number of favorable outcomes would be $3!6!=241920$. Am I right?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova: Yep! That's correct